# Swi Prolog Relation

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a relation split in Prolog that takes an integer N, a list L of integers, and other parameters, list L is flat. The relation split returns true if the list L can be divided into three subsets, such that the sum of the integers in each subset is strictly less than N. Otherwise, the relation returns false. This is the furthest I've gone so far:

```
split(list, list, list, list)
split([],[],[],[]).
list_sum([],0).
split([X|L], [X|L1], [X|L2], L3):-
list_sum([Head + Tail]),
list_sum>N,
!,
split(N, L,L1, L2, L3).
```

?- ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: list_sum/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
Any help and explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: that cannot be real code !

Comment: You need to go further.

Comment: To give some useful advice: start by writing down the solution algorithm in your own words, and share that with us.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your problem is that you need to go learn Prolog. I'm not kidding. You're going to fail your class if you think you can get away with this level of "not getting it" and pick up the rest on S.O.

1. What's that first line, a comment? Put the comment character there.
2. What is `list_sum/2` doing there in the middle of your `split/4` definition?
3. Unless you're trying to create some kind of difference list or destructuring arithmetic, `[Head + Tail]` will absolutely not do what you want.
4. What is `list_sum>N` supposed to mean on the next line? There is only one namespace in Prolog and the language is very, very dependent on getting your capitalization right. Being this sloppy does not bode well.
5. Why are you cutting on line 7?
6. Your last line is defining `split/5` when the previous two rule heads (I think?) are defining `split/4`. This cannot be what you mean.
7. You're pattern-matching on line 4 requires that all three of the lists begin with the same value, which seems like a pretty special special-case considering you have no other in which you meaningfully examine the elements of the lists.

In my opinion this code is totally unsalvagable. Throw it away and start over. And read through a tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

To your exact question: you have **not** defined a predicate `list_sum` with two arguments in the "code" that you have shown. This is what the error is telling you.